# ASP.Net XML fails to render parent element node using append.Child method

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an EmptyTemplate control placed in a gridview that contains **two textbox** and one **linkbutton** control. Upon clicking the link button control, the data entered into the textboxes are copied over into an xml file.

script -repost

```
Public Sub writeStartpoNum(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim startpoNumID As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNumID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim startpoNum As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNum"), TextBox).Text

        Dim oDs As New DataSet()
        oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
        oDs.Tables.Clear()
        oDs.DataSetName = "newshipmentnotification"
        oDs.Tables.Add("pos")
        oDs.Tables("pos").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
        oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        oDs.Tables.Add("po")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumberID")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumber")

        Dim pos_po As DataRelation = oDs.Relations.Add("pos_po", oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id"), _
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id"))
        pos_po.Nested = True

        Dim oDrs As DataRow = oDs.Tables("pos").NewRow
        oDrs("pos_Id") = 0
        oDs.Tables("pos").Rows.Add(oDrs)

        Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow
        oDr("ponumberID") = startpoNumID
        oDr("ponumber") = startpoNum
        oDr("pos_Id") = 0
        oDs.Tables("po").Rows.Add(oDr)
        oDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to completely change it. Post a new question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in this way:

**EDIT : Changed to reflect changed requirement**

```
    'Create nodes for start-up purchase order number 
  Public Sub writeStartpoNum(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim startpoNumID As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNumID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim startpoNum As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNum"), TextBox).Text

        Dim oDs As New DataSet()
        Dim xmlPath As String = MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml")

        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath) Then
            'oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
            'oDs.Tables.Clear()
            oDs.DataSetName = "newshipmentnotification"
            oDs.Tables.Add("pos")
            oDs.Tables("pos").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
            oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
            oDs.Tables.Add("po")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumberID")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumber")

            Dim pos_po As DataRelation = oDs.Relations.Add("pos_po", oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id"), _
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id"))
            pos_po.Nested = True

            Dim oDrs As DataRow = oDs.Tables("pos").NewRow
            oDrs("pos_Id") = 0
            oDs.Tables("pos").Rows.Add(oDrs)
       Else
            oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml")) 
       End If
        Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow
        oDr("ponumberID") = startpoNumID
        oDr("ponumber") = startpoNum
        oDr("pos_Id") = 0
        oDs.Tables("po").Rows.Add(oDr)
        oDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
        gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataSource = oDs.Tables("po")
        gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Comment: I took things a little further with the form. However, I ran into an issue with the "emptydatatemplate" being used in the Gridview. The contents of the emptydatatemplate inserts the data correctly and all is well formatted, but after the data is inputted via the emptydatatemplate, the Gridview does not show; I still get the emptydatatemplate. When I comment out the ClearXMLFile() function, I can see the Gridview and its data that was populated in the XML file. When you have a moment, could we further discuss tomorrow? I'm Updating the post with my code. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: I have updated the answer to refresh the gridview. It should be ok now.

Comment: I cannot figure out while I'm getting an object-reference related error on this line: Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow  ...The conditional statements checks if the file exist and if not, to build out the xml. When debugged, it still says that the dataset: oDs has zero tables. Any other suggestions please? What could I be missing here?

Comment: This will happen when oDs Dataset does not have a table "po". Step through the method, see if it goes through 'IF' or 'Else' part. If it goes through 'Else' part, xml file has issue.